# Am I doing a log transformation of data correctly?

Tags: python, statistics, pandas

I'm doing some exploratory data analysis on some data and I get these histograms:

[image]

That looks like a candidate for a log transformation on the data, so I run the following Python code to transform the data:

```
df["abv"].apply(np.log).hist()
df["ibu"].apply(np.log).hist()
plt.show()
```

And I get this new plot of the transformed histograms:

[image]

Am I correct that a log transform was ok to do in this case, and if so, what's the best way to interpret the results?

Comment: Try calling `hist(logx=True)` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, log transform seems a good solution for better interpretation. Overlap between these two datasets is really small, so, only by looking at the plot, you can say with high certainty, that they are significantly different from each-other.

Comment: Between this and what @Emre mentioned, it got me on the right track!